# Why does SQL Server 2008 R2 IntelliSense fail after calling a user-defined function?

Tags: sql-server

While editing a User-Defined function, Intellisense works fine prior to the use of an existing UDF.  After that, it no longer works.

...Previous code

```
declare 
     @FirstDayOfMonth DATETIME
    ,@LastDayOfMonth DATETIME

--****Intellisense works here
select 
    @FirstDayOfMonth = dbo.udf_GetFirstDayOfMonth( @EUDATE )
    ,@LastDayOfMonth = dbo.udf_GetLastDayOfMonth( @EUDATE )

--****From here on, Intellisense no longer works
```

IF I comment out the call to the UDF's Intellisense works throughout the rest of the function.

Comment: Because the native intellisense in 2008 is horrible. You may have to refresh the local cache or maybe even reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Refresh your Local Cache`, there are two ways of doing it.

1-  Press <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`R`</kbd>

2 - Go to --> `Edit` --> `IntelliSense` --> `Refresh Local Cache`

[image]

Comment: Cache has been refreshed. SSMS closed and opened again.

Comment: I do find that in SSMS 2016 this is not an issue. I'll chalk it up to that version's limitations.